# Modifying python interpreter settings in Windows 8.1 command prompt

Tags: python-2.7, command-prompt, interpreter

I'm using the default interpreter in the command prompt on Windows 8.1 and 64 bit Python 2.7. (via typing python then writing code in there)

I write code in Notepad++, then paste it into the interpreter, sometimes writing things on the interpreter inbetween. However sometimes it forgets newlines and pastes my copied text is if it is one line. Sometimes all the commands are remembered as well (if I press up or down), even between closing and opening the interpreter in the command prompt, which is nice. Sometimes the commands are only saved for every other instance of the interpreter.

What is the reason for this behavior? Is there some setting that I can't find that controls this?

Comment: Don't you want to start the code right out of Notepad++?

Comment: What do you mean? I use it in the command prompt so then I can type things myself alongside snippets typed in Notepad++

Comment: You should just write complete files and save them as files from Notepad++, unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: Yea and I do in general. Just sometimes when I'm testing little snippets of code (like say portions of functions in server code) it's nicer to use the interpreter. And either way whether or not to use the interpreter is besides the point - there is the option to use it and I would simply like to know how.

Comment: The history buffers are implemented in the console host process, conhost.exe. Maybe adding more history buffers in the console properties (and default properties) will help keep the history available for all attached processes. FYI, you can scroll through the history using the F7 pop up menu. You can also run `doskey.exe /history`, which works via the undocumented console API function `GetConsoleCommandHistory`, which returns the command history for a particular executable name (e.g. "python.exe"). It's too bad there's no matching `Set` function to load a history file.

Comment: For entering multi-line input in the console I typically use `exec r'''` [paste] '''`. I avoid the normal "single" compiling for multi-line input because it tends to be temperamental and throw syntax errors. The default "module" mode of `exec` is more forgiving.